# Fancybox 2 horizontal animation

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Seems an easy request, making Fancybox 2 animate slides horizontally, instead of vertically. But I couldn't find any resource on how to do this, or whether it's possible at all or not.

Anyone has any kind of solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there's any options that allow you to do this (anyone please correct me if I'm wrong) but it's easy enough to achieve.
on line 1289 change all instances of '.top' to '.left'

```
if (elastic) {
    startPos.left = getValue(parseInt(startPos.left, 10) - 200);
    endPos.left = '+=200px';
}
```

on line 1314 do the same

```
if (effect === 'elastic') {
    endPos.left = '+=200px';
}
```

This will slide the gallery items in from the left.
Cheers
You can't use the minified version of the file.